# Vim and CScope issues

Tags: vim, plugins

I'm trying to get Vim and CScope set up. A friend of mine has it set up, and it's working well, but when I try to run `:cs find f (anything!)` Vim outputs:

> E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version.

I've tried with Vim 7.2 and 7.3 with CScope Version 15.7a and 16.0a.

I'm trying to edit inside a Rails application.

Comment: Does ":echo has('cscope')" show a 1 or a 0? If 0, your version of Vim doesn't have support for cscope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure **+cscope** is built in vim.

```
vim --version
```

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 27 2010 17:51:38)
MS-Windows 32-bit console version
Included patches: 1-46
Compiled by Bram@KIBAALE
Big version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
+conceal +cryptv **+cscope** +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs
...

Comment: That was it. I just didn't know how to check. Rebuilt it with scope support, and I'm in business. Thank you!

Comment: `find $(pwd) -name '.*' -prune -o \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.c' \) -print | cscope -bi-`

Comment: `export CSCOPE_DB=/path/to/cscope.out`